# How to select whole words in NetBeans instead of sub-words (like in Visual Studio/Notepad++/MS Word/etc)?

Tags: netbeans

How to select whole words in NetBeans instead subwords (like in Qt / VisualStudio / Any other text editor).

E.g.:

```
AAA_BBB_CCC - AAA_BBB_CCC
AaaBbbCcc - AaaBbbCcc
```

If select this in NetBeans using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> the `AAA/Aaa` will be selected instead `AAA_BBB_CCC/AaaBbbCcc` like in Visual Studio/Notepad++/MS Word/etc.

How this option named in Keymap options? `"Extend selection to End of Word"` stops selection on the first space.

Comment: What version of NetBeans? In 8.2 it selects `AAA_BBB_CCC`.

Comment: Yes. 8.2 ("Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)"). And NO, it selects `AAA`, then `_`, then `BBB`... I did not find option for this. Nearest in meaning is "Extend selection to End of Word" but is stops on first space (will be stoppet between `AAA_BBB_CCC` and ` -  AAA_BBB_CCC` ). Currently `Ctrl+Shift+Right` is `Extend Selection to Next Word`.

Comment: it is a bit complicated to use, but I just changed Ctrl+Shift+Right to "Extend selection to End of Word", and when I need to go beyond the space, I just release the Ctrl key, and it is quite annoying... We have no option like "Ignore SPACES when Extending selection of Words" :(. The same problem with "Insertion point to next word", I changed the hotkey to end of word.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3, follow this path:
Tools > Options > Editor (from ribbon) > General (from tabs) > Under `Camel case Behaviour` section uncheck `Enable Camel Case Navigation`.
NetBeans 8.2 also had an option for it, but currently I havn't it to check.

[image]